# Rails 5 - Connecting mLab MongoDB instance to Heroku

Tags: mongodb, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, mlab

**Rails 5 app on Cloud 9 IDE with MongoDB v3.0.12** - working fine on local server.

First I initiated a MongoDB instance on mLab.com and imported my data.

Then added Heroku config (I typed my actual db username & password below)

```
$ heroku config:add MONGOLAB_URI=mongodb://dbuser:dbpass@dbhost/dbname
```

Then added production profile to config/mongoid.yml

```
production:
  clients:
    default:
      uri: <%= ENV['MONGOLAB_URI'] %>
      options:
        connect_timeout: 15
```

After pushing to Heroku, the app doesn't work and Heroku logs shows this error:

-Username and password should be urlencoded

-Mongo::Error::InvalidURI

Can anyone guide me how to make it run on Heroku.

[image]

Comment: Could not figure it out. Used Mlab Add on in Heroku and it worked. Thanks.